# Missing Open File Tabs

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm not sure exactly what I did, but Visual Studio is no longer showing the tabs for currently open files.  How can I get them back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools -> Options... -> Enviroment -> General -> Window Layout -> Tabbed documents